# Python, Kivy - QRScanner and ScreenManager

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I want to create an app with 2 (an more) screens (screen manager).
When i make app without that QR reader, i know how to move values from one screen to another. But here i have problem with that.
I spend 3 days on this problem and still dont have answer. Can You help me?
Heres code:
https://github.com/fornakter/Terminarz-Kivy-MD/blob/master/main.py
Errors are on class SecoundWindow, on line 16.
Comments explained errors wit i recive.
Thank You.

Comment: Looks like an error involving non-existent `ids`. Please post your code and your `kv`. (or at least a [mcve]).

Comment: Theres in "main" folder here: https://github.com/fornakter/Terminarz-Kivy-MD
I know what "non-existent ids" means. That code works on one-screen app, so problem must be on communication on screens. Also familiar code works with different apps (with no cam, simple app).

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://github.com/Android-for-Python/camera4kivy#connect-camera) says `connect_camera()` must be called after `on_start()`. So change the definition of `SecoundWindow` to simply:

```
class SecoundWindow(Screen):
    pass
```

And in your `ReadQR` App, add the following methods:

```
def on_start(self):
    Clock.schedule_once(self.connect_camera)

def connect_camera(self, dt):
    secoundWindow = self.root.get_screen('secound')
    secoundWindow.ids.preview.connect_camera(camera_id='front', enable_analyze_pixels=True, default_zoom=0.0)
```

I needed to add `camera_id` to avoid SEGFAULT.

Unrelated, but the following lines of your code do nothing and can be deleted:

```
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(FirstWindow(name='first'))
sm.add_widget(SecoundWindow(name='secound'))
```